# Comsume WCF from C# Error

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a C# WCF service that I'm trying to consume via my C# client application, but getting errors. Below is information regarding the setup.

**Web.Config File**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="Proactive_WebAPI.Services">
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint
            address="http://api.proactiveclothing.com/services/Product.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
            contract="Proactive.Product.ProductDataService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpsBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="../../wsdl/ProductDataService.wsdl"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>   
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I've added the Service path as a reference to my c# client app and here is the code I use to access it.

```
    ServiceReference3.ProductDataServiceClient f = new ServiceReference3.ProductDataServiceClient();

    ServiceReference3.GetProductSellableRequest req = new ServiceReference3.GetProductSellableRequest();
    req.password = "xxxxx";
    req.productId = "000";
    f.getProductSellable(req);
```

**Exception Details**

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/ProductDataService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at ServiceReference3.ProductDataService.getProductSellable(getProductSellableRequest1 request)
       at ServiceReference3.ProductDataServiceClient.ServiceReference3.ProductDataService.getProductSellable(getProductSellableRequest1 request) in c:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\8c312d07\39684625\App_WebReferences.lc9jzddi.4.cs:line 3477
       at ServiceReference3.ProductDataServiceClient.getProductSellable(GetProductSellableRequest GetProductSellableRequest) in c:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\8c312d07\39684625\App_WebReferences.lc9jzddi.4.cs:line 3483
       at WebService.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Websites\5. Stand Alone Applications\PastelSDK\WebService.aspx.cs:line 26
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       InnerException:
```

**Edit**

Modified the web.config file in client as follows

```
<endpoint address="http://api.proactiveclothing.com/services/Product.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="ProductDataServiceBinding2" contract="ServiceReference3.ProductDataService"
        name="ProductDataServiceBinding1" />
```

I now get the following error

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ProductDataService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at ServiceReference3.ProductDataService.getProductSellable(getProductSellableRequest1 request)
       at ServiceReference3.ProductDataServiceClient.ServiceReference3.ProductDataService.getProductSellable(getProductSellableRequest1 request) in c:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\8c312d07\39684625\App_WebReferences.lc9jzddi.4.cs:line 3477
       at ServiceReference3.ProductDataServiceClient.getProductSellable(GetProductSellableRequest GetProductSellableRequest) in c:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\8c312d07\39684625\App_WebReferences.lc9jzddi.4.cs:line 3483
       at WebService.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Websites\5. Stand Alone Applications\PastelSDK\WebService.aspx.cs:line 27
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you check if in Solution Explorer, under the Web service references for the project, you have defined any references to this web service?

Comment: @Sparrow I have a reference to the WCF under App_WebReferences  and can instantiate it in code.

Comment: What happens if you fire up WCF test client and try to put those end points in? May help you pinpoint if the issue is in the your wcf service or the client. Dumb question but what happens if you right click your service ref and click update on your client now that you've switch off localhost.

Comment: @TravisActon I'll give it a try now.

Comment: @TravisActon I get the following error:  "Warning: No code was generated.If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or servicesor because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option."

Comment: It's almost like it can't find that wsdl on the path you have defined. Everything else looks good to me.

Comment: so related errors point to a permissions issue with the application pool account in which the service runs under. Anyway you could elevate the permissions on that account to rule that out? I believe others were talking about permission issues to the c:windows\temp directory

Comment: @TravisActon I think there is a mismatch somewhere. Changing permissions would pose a security risk I think, which our senior guys would not go for.